# HDInsight HBase, configure hbase using blob

Tags: hbase, azure-hdinsight

I am now doing some research about hbase using object store instead of hdfs, I can not found any document about this. Right now, I have a cluster with HDFS and HBase on it, I can configure Hadoop using  Blob, I could run some commands successfully like :

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /root/x.sh wasb://xx.@xx.blob.core.windows.net/
```

but, I could not even start HBase if I enable Blob and change `hbase.rootdir` to `wasb://xx.@xx.blob.core.windows.net/`

Is there any configuration document that I can refer to, thanks

Answer (score 0):

HDinsight has HBase as specialized cluster type. You can get started here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-hbase-tutorial-get-started-linux/

In HDInisght , you provide a default storage account & container for HBase during cluster creation time.